# SQL Error when trying to use a loop?

Tags: mysql, sql

currently having problems with the following SQL code, appears to give a SQL error and I have no idea why its giving it because previous @SET values have worked fine.

SQL:

```
SET @i1 = 4500000;
SET @i2 = 10;

SET @cnt = 1;

WHILE @cnt < 125
BEGIN
   `INSERT INTO ix12 (entry, ix2) VALUES (@i1, @i2);
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
   SET @i1 = @i1 + 1;
END;
```

Error:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHILE @cnt < 125
>       BEGIN
>          INSERT INTO ix12 (entry, ix2) VALUES (@i1, @i2)' at line 1 */

Any help as to why its throwing out the SQL error would be appreciated.

Comment: How is HeidiSQL involved in this question?

Comment: Control flow expressions are only allowed in programming blocks -- for stored functions, procedures, and triggers.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How would the SQL have to look to be able to be executed in a SQL program?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
SET @cnt = 1;

WHILE @cnt < 125
```

to

```
DECLARE @cnt int = 1

WHILE @cnt < 125
```